# wpf datagrid foreground binding to item's property programmaticaly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I have a WPF `DataGrid` control with runtime generated columns. As its `ItemsSource` I set a generic List of `ExamineExampleDataGridItem`:

```
public class ExamineExamplesDataGridItem
{
    public List<string> PredictiveAttributeValues { get; set; }
    public string DecisiveAttributeValue { get; set; }
    public string ExaminedAttributeValue { get; set; }

    public Brush ExaminedAttributeValueColor
    {
        // if I set a debug point here, I'll get there, but it makes no sense
        get
        {
            return DecisiveAttributeValue == null || ExaminedAttributeValue == null
                ? Brushes.Black
                : DecisiveAttributeValue.Equals(ExaminedAttributeValue) ? Brushes.Green : Brushes.Red;
        }
        set { }
    }
}
```

When binding fields to the `DataGrid` instance, everything works fine except coloring:

```
List<ExamineExamplesDataGridItem> items = new List<ExamineExamplesDataGridItem>();

// several columns, works fine
for (int i = 0; i < _attributeTypeSet.PredictiveAttributeTypes.Count; i++)
{
    DataGridComboBoxColumn attributeTypeColumn = new DataGridComboBoxColumn()
    {
        TextBinding = new Binding("PredictiveAttributeValues[" + i + "]")
    };
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(attributeTypeColumn);
}

// prev last column, works fine
DataGridComboBoxColumn decisiveComboBoxColumn = new DataGridComboBoxColumn()
{
    CellStyle =
        new Style(typeof (DataGridCell)) {Setters = {new Setter() {Property = ForegroundProperty, Value = Brushes.Blue}}}
};
dataGrid.Columns.Add(decisiveComboBoxColumn);

// last column, which content I want to color
DataGridTextColumn examinedColumn = new DataGridTextColumn()
{
    ElementStyle = new Style()
    {
        TargetType = typeof(TextBlock),
        Setters =
        {
            // this works, but..
            // new Setter(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red)

            // ... I need this one. It calls ExaminedAttributeValueColor property, but displays black color anyway
            new Setter(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, new Binding("ExaminedAttributeValueColor"))
        }
    }
};
dataGrid.Columns.Add(examinedColumn);

dataGrid.ItemsSource = items;
```

When populating `ItemsSource` its color stays black. I also tried to bind `CellStyle` instead of `ElementStyle` like this:

```
CellStyle = new Style()
{
    TargetType = typeof(DataGridCell),
    Setters =
    {
        new Setter(DataGridCell.ForegroundProperty, new Binding("ExaminedAttributeValueColor"))
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, just like `ElementStyle`. I found a lot of troubleshoots, but they are all about XAML coding. Is it possible to do what I want from C# code? How should I do it? Should I use something other than the `CellStyle` or `ElementStyle` property? I saw the `FontStyle` property of `DataGridTextColumn`, but as I know it just defines a font family.

Comment: The reason that all the examples that you find are in XAML coding is because that's the best way to do it.... using the MVVM pattern....

Comment: The reason I decided to define dataGrid in C# code is that I need to define columns in runtime. I'm new in WPF and for me it was the easyest way to do it. Anyway there should be solution in my case, shouldn't it?

Comment: Anything is possible but that doesn't mean it's right.... In WPF\XAML the easiest way is not normally the best way... take a look at http://www.wpftutorial.net/datagrid.html.  I can see Binding, Style, Setter and references to UI controls, in your C# code. That can ALL be done far easier in XAML. If you put the effort into mastering XAML you'll find that it's far easier in the XAML than it is in code-behind. Honestly, I faced the same problem myself 5 years ago....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very quick and basic example of setting the Foreground and Background of cells in a DataGrid plus adding a Combobox for a drop-down collection of items, following the MVVM pattern

First we create a BasePropertyChanged class implements INotifyPropertyChanged, it is inherited wherever we want a change to a property value to notify the UI

```
public class BasePropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is your 'ExamineExamplesDataGridItem' class, I had to just make something up here cos I don't know what yours looks like.....

```
public class ExamineExamplesDataGridItem : BasePropertyChanged
{


    public ExamineExamplesDataGridItem()
    {
        PredictiveAttributeValues = new List<string>();
        PredictiveAttributeValues.Add("Predict 1");
        PredictiveAttributeValues.Add("Predict 2");
        PredictiveAttributeValues.Add("Predict 3");
        PredictiveAttributeValues.Add("Predict 4");
        PredictiveAttributeValues.Add("Predict 5");
    }

    private List<string> _PredictiveAttributeValues;

    public List<string> PredictiveAttributeValues
    {
        get { return _PredictiveAttributeValues; }
        set { _PredictiveAttributeValues = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("PredictiveAttributeValues"); }
    }

    private string _Coll1;

    public string Coll1
    {
        get { return _Coll1; }
        set { _Coll1 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Coll1"); }
    }

    private string _Coll2;

    public string Coll2
    {
        get { return _Coll2; }
        set { _Coll2 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Coll2"); }
    }
}
```

}

Here is the ViewModel that your View (XAML) binds to, its task is to simply maintain the state of the data in your application, when the data changes (here in the ViewModel) as the result of inputs from the user or updates from external source (i.e. data base) then the View is updated (using Binding and DataContext)

```
class Base_ViewModel : BasePropertyChanged
{

    private List<ExamineExamplesDataGridItem> _items;

    public List<ExamineExamplesDataGridItem> items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("items"); }
    }

    public Base_ViewModel()
    {
        items = new List<ExamineExamplesDataGridItem>();
        items.Add(new ExamineExamplesDataGridItem() { Coll1 = "Row 1 Col 1", Coll2 = "Row 1 Col 2" });
        items.Add(new ExamineExamplesDataGridItem() { Coll1 = "Row 2 Col 1", Coll2 = "Row 2 Col 2" });
        items.Add(new ExamineExamplesDataGridItem() { Coll1 = "Row 3 Col 1", Coll2 = "Row 3 Col 2" });
    }
}
```

Here is the XAML, notice how all the Style, Setters and Binding is done in the XAML...

```
<Grid>

    <DataGrid Name="DataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding items}" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Combobox">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding PredictiveAttributeValues}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> 
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Coll1}" Header="Column 1">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="Background"  Value="Blue" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Coll2}" Header="Column 2">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="Background"  Value="Red" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

and lastly the Data Context..... NOW, I have set this in the code-behind merely to simplify this example BUT ordinarily EVEN this one line of code would go in the XAML but that would need a more complex XAML code because you need to add the reference to that ViewModel in the XAML using the application name and I don't know what [your] application is call or your folder structure

```
// in the Code - Behind file of you WPF Window
InitializeComponent();
// Set Data Context for the View
this.DataContext = new Base_ViewModel();
```

It looks like a lot of code I know, but when you break it down there isn't much there really. The thing is that you are now free to style and modify you UI controls in the XAML.... the final test is this.... in a pure MVVM application you should be able to comment out ALL the UI controls (in the XAML) AND the code STILL compiles without any errors.....

Comment: That's is not what I need indeed. But, I guess, using this stuff, I can do what I need. Anyway I'll write about results. Thanks for your answer!